# VueJs shuffles the elements of my gallery

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, owl-carousel

I've created a gallery component with vuejs, using Owl Carousel

When you select a product(**[check here, in desktop please](https://regalospersonales.com/libretas-personalizadas-totales)**) the gallery changes dynamically, the problem is that the large photos do not correspond to the selected thumbnail.

I checked the chrome console and the v-for loop indexes are shuffling.

what am I doing wrong?

**Vue.js v2.5.16** and **Owl Carousel v2.2.0**

This is my gallery vue component:

```
Vue.component('product-gallery', {

    template : '<div>\
                    <template v-if="article == null">\
                        <div :style="styleLoader">\
                          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" :style="styleSpinner"></i>\
                        </div>\
                    </template>\
                    <template v-else>\
                        <div id="responsive_gallery" class="owl-carousel owl-theme rp-owl-slider">\
                          <div v-if="design_image" class="item">\
                            <img class="owl-lazy" :data-src="design_image" :data-src-retina="design_image" alt="design" title="design">\
                          </div>\
                          <div class="item" v-for="(item,index) in article.total_images">\
                              <a :href="_getImgUrl(index,750)" :title="article.seo_title" :alt="article.seo_title" class="zoom_foto" target="_blank" rel="gallery">\
                                  <img class="owl-lazy" :data-src="_getImgUrl(index,512)" :data-src-retina="_getImgUrl(index,1024)" :alt="article.seo_title" :title="article.seo_title" itemprop="image">\
                              </a>\
                          </div>\
                          <template v-if="total_videos > 0 && videos">\
                            <div class="owl-item-video" v-for="video in videos">\
                              <div class="owl-item-video"><a class="owl-video" :href="video.video_file.url"></a></div>\
                            </div>\
                          </template>\
                            </div>\
                        <div class="row">\
                            <div class="col-xs-12">\
                                <div id="gallery_thumbnails" class="gallery-thumbnails" style="display:none;">\
                                    <div v-if="design_image" class="item col-2">\
                                      <img :src="design_image" class="img-fluid" alt="design-thumbnail" title="design-thumbnail">\
                                    </div>\
                                    <div v-for="(thumb,index) in article.total_images" class="item col-xs-2" :class="{active: index == 0 && !design_image}">\
                                        <img :src="_getImgUrl(index,100)" class="img-fluid" :title="article.seo_title" :alt="article.seo_title">\
                                    </div>\
                                    <template v-if="total_videos > 0 && videos">\
                                      <div class="item thumb-video-item col-2" v-for="video in videos">\
                                        <img :src="_getVideoThumbUrl(video.video_file.youtube_id)" alt="Video" class="img-fluid">\
                                        <div class="owl-video-play-icon-thumb"></div>\
                                       </div>\
                                    </template>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </template>\
                </div>\
                ',    


    data: function()
    {
       return {
            resource : null,
            article  : null,
            styleLoader: {
              position: 'relative',
              textAlign: 'center',
              height: '600px'
            },
            styleSpinner: {
              color: 'gray',
              marginTop: 600/2 + 'px',
              fontSize: '60px'
            }

       }
    },

    props : ['design_image','videos','total_videos'],

    updated: function () 
    {        


       $('#responsive_gallery').trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-loaded');
       $('#responsive_gallery').find('.owl-item').remove();

       // $('#responsive_gallery').html($('#responsive_gallery').find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-loaded');
       $('#responsive_gallery').owlCarousel({
          items:1,
          singleItem : true,
          slideSpeed : 1000,
          nav: true,
          video:true,
          lazyLoad: true,
          afterInit : $('.gallery-thumbnails').show(),
          afterAction : this._syncPosition,
          responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
          navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"],
       }).on('changed.owl.carousel', this._syncPosition);

       $('#gallery_thumbnails .item').on('click', function(event) 
       {
          $('#responsive_gallery').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$('#gallery_thumbnails .item').index(this), 0, true]);
       });


       console.log('Article Total Images: ' + this.article.total_images)
       console.log('Owl Items generated: ' + $('#responsive_gallery .owl-item').length);         

    },

    methods: {      

        _getImgUrl : function(index,size) {  

            index = index +1;

            if(!this.article.group)
              return FotiApiServices.helpers.getArticleImgURL(this.article.article_id, size, index, this.article.seo_slug);
            else
              return FotiApiServices.helpers.getGroupImgURL(this.article.article_id, size, index, this.article.seo_slug);


        },

       _getVideoThumbUrl : function(video_id) {

          return 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + video_id + '/0.jpg';

       },

        _syncPosition: function(el) {

            var current = el.item.index;

            $("#gallery_thumbnails")
              .find(".item")
              .removeClass("active")
              .eq(current)
              .addClass("active")

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You are trying to manage the DOM simultaneously with Vue and Owl - this ain't come with a happy end. Use either one of them - but not both.

Comment: @IVOGELOV How would you leave this code right then? Thanks

Comment: Probably will use https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/ or a similar Vue component.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use it because it doesn't have lazy load and retina image.

Comment: The problem is that Vue tries to keep the real DOM in sync with its virtual DOM. But Owl updates only the real DOM because it does not know about the Vue's virtual DOM. And thus Owl leaves the real and virtual DOM out of sync - so the next time Vue thinks it has to re-render the template, it gets confused because it left the real DOM in different state than it is currently.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Wow, thanks, could you say some  patch to fix the bug?

Comment: do you have a solution, I am looking for the same.